# LabDaq - sending attachment

Tags: mirth

I would like to attach a PDF file as the "result" for a LabDaq test and have it sent out through all the HL7 interfaces.  The PDF file is not generated by LabDaq but rather added as an attachment.  We see a way to select to have all attachments forwarded.  However, we don't want to make a universal change for all attachments but rather a specific change for select attachments.  For reference, the attachments are reference lab results.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the Mirth (Nextgen) Connect's Attachment Handler.

There's an overview on how to use it on the [User Guide](https://www.nextgen.com/-/media/files/nextgen-connect/nextgen-connect-38-user-guide.pdf) or on this blog post https://kailo.tech/health-it/mirth-connect-bits/mirth-connect-attachment-handler/

The blog post should explain how you can read a file and use the base64 string on an HL7 message.